# How to speed up a MySQL query on shared hosting?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run query for little count that a client requested.

I am working on site which have 73,000+ trainees and it can grow more and more. My site is hosted on Godaddy server.

Also a trainee can have more than one training, and it happens to have that client wanted to show count that how many trainings are being taken by trainees.

The thing is there is also `WHERE` and `LIKE`s applied on query because which I think query is not executing as it becomes too much for the database.

How can I make this faster (if not fast then even execute it)?

After too much wait I get an Apache server error.

This is how it should work and it works fine locally on my machine with local database and 1,000+ records.

[image]

But online I am receiving this error:

[image]

Is it that the server is not powerful enough, or does the query need to be fixed?

### Update for explanation of my problem

These are some table structures I have:

```
/*Table structure for table `ml_district` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ml_district`;

CREATE TABLE `ml_district` (
  `District_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `District` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `trashed` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`District_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Table structure for table `organisation` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `organisation`;

CREATE TABLE `organisation` (
  `Organisation_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `District_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Province_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `school_Dept_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone_no` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mobile_no` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trashed` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Organisation_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=77437 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Table structure for table `trainee` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `trainee`;

CREATE TABLE `trainee` (
  `Trainee_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Gender_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `BPS_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Designation_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Organisation_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Trainee_name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `father_husband_name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CNIC` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mobile_no` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trashed` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Trainee_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CNICUnique` (`CNIC`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=73266 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Table structure for table `trainee_training_enrolment` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `trainee_training_enrolment`;

CREATE TABLE `trainee_training_enrolment` (
  `Enrolment_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Trainee_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `schedule_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `trashed` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Enrolment_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=112512 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Also my query is something like this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(1) AS Total 
FROM
  `trainee` `T` 
  LEFT JOIN `ml_designation` `MLDG` 
    ON `MLDG`.`Designation_id` = `T`.`Designation_id` 
    AND `MLDG`.`trashed` = 0 
  LEFT JOIN `organisation` `O` 
    ON `O`.`Organisation_id` = `T`.`Organisation_id` 
    AND `O`.`trashed` = 0 
  LEFT JOIN `trainee_training_enrolment` `TTE` 
    ON `TTE`.`Trainee_id` = `T`.`Trainee_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `ml_district` `MLD` 
    ON `MLD`.`District_id` = `O`.`District_id` 
    AND `MLD`.`trashed` = 0 
  LEFT JOIN `ml_gender` `MLG` 
    ON `MLG`.`Gender_id` = `T`.`Gender_id` 
    AND `MLG`.`trashed` = 0 
WHERE (LOWER(Trainee_name) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(T.CNIC) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(MLD.District) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(O.school_Dept_name) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(T.father_husband_name) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(T.father_husband_name) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(MLG.Gender) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(T.Mobile_no) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!') 
  AND `T`.`trashed` = 0 
  AND `T`.`Gender_id` = '1'
```

Comment: Look at what indexes you have on tables that the slow query is using (you do have indexes on the tables don't you).... run an EXPLAIN to see how MySQL is executing the query. Show the table structures and indexes, and the query, and the result of the EXPLAIN inyour question

Comment: But we can't answer your question without this type of information

Comment: This will be much easier to answer if you can provide the actual query.

However, sql parts like `where training like "%exercise%"` tend to be slow as mysql won't be able to use an index.

Comment: It would be better that before even building the database you analyze what kind of queries you want to do. And then build appropriate indexes on the keys. Also, 73000 is a very small number. MySQL should be fast enough.

Comment: Write the query you are executing. You can hope on a bad configured query or not setting indexes as reasons of slow queries

Comment: @MarkBaker, i updated my question sir. Please Review. Let me know if there is anything else i should provide.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on any of these tables?

Comment: Do you have to use LIKE on all those conditions, or can you use `=` instead.... LIKE doesn't really seem appropriate for conditions like GENDER

Comment: @MarkBaker
Yes you are right. but i used like on it cuz i want to keep the query intact with the datatables. there are two queries running. 1 is for datatables and 1 this.

as i want to show record for datatables above the datatables. the other datatable query is executed by the datatable library of codeigniter named "igniedtables".

if i remove like from here i will also have to remove from datatables. which is fine by me but i am not sure it will fix the problem.

Comment: LIKE is generally inefficient, and can't use indexes if your criteria begins with `%`..... that means it has to do a full table scan.... and `Female` also matches `LIKE '%male%'`; so it won't even give correct results.... use `=` where you can.

Comment: Similarly, try to use `=` for any criteria that's selected from a dropdown, where the exact match should be known

Comment: If your select options were key/value; then search against the `trainee` record by the key and you won't need the JOIN at all; better to do that than to use the JOIN and search against the value from the JOINed table

Answer (score 1):

From your query, you could set fulltext indexes on the

```
(LOWER(Trainee_name) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(T.CNIC) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(MLD.District) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(O.school_Dept_name) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(T.father_husband_name) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(T.father_husband_name) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(MLG.Gender) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!' 
  OR LOWER(T.Mobile_no) LIKE '%m%' ESCAPE '!')
```

and use match instead of like
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

As a means of boosting its execute time
(full-text indexes work only with myISAM engine)

Comment: i don't know how to set full text indexes.. but i will look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need an index on *trainee_training_enrolment.Trainee_id*

Without that index MySQL have to full scan *trainee_training_enrolment* for each trainee (with *trashed = 0 AND Gender_id = '1'*).